# Rails 3.2 assets not recompiling on page refresh

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading an old 2.3.18 app to 3.2.17, and encountering a weird issue with asset pipeline.

When editing a file that is either `//= require` in my `/app/assets/application.js` or `@import`ed in my `/app/assets/application.css.scss`, none of the changes take effect on page refresh.

The only way I can get the assets to recompile on page refresh is to make an edit to the `application.js` or `application.css.scss` file, save, and then refresh.

I dont have any compiled assets in `/public/assets`.

My `development.rb`:

```
Com::Application.configure do

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  # config.action_view.debug_rjs           = true

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  # ensure we can access static assets in /public
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Automatically inject JavaScript needed for LiveReload
  config.middleware.insert_before(::Rack::Lock, ::Rack::LiveReload)
end
```